# Ember-data and #each

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to follow the example in the Ember guide but with ember-data. Here is my router:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true,
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      redirectsTo: 'orders'
    }),
    orders: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/orders',
      connectOutlets: function(router) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('orders', App.store.findAll(App.Order));
      }
    }),
    order: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/orders/:ord_id'
    })
  })
});
```

And in my template:

```
{{#each order in controller}}
...
{{/each}}
```

I get this error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.split')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works using an ArrayController. I changed this:

App.OrdersController = Ember.Controller.extend();

to this:

App.OrdersController = Ember.Controller.extend();